# DocuSign RestAPI: How to send pdf document and apply template to the document with HTTP POST request C#

Tags: c#, xml, httprequest, docusignapi

I'm new to REST API and DocuSign. I'm trying to upload a document on which I would like to apply the web template that I created in my account.

Here's the code I have so far (I'm referring to the following code https://gist.github.com/Ergin008/4165742) but it doesn't show how to attach new PDF document with my request and apply existing template to the new pdf while making API call. Any sample code or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
            HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information", "GET", null, username, password, integratorKey);

            string response = getResponseBody(request);

            baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(response, "baseUrl");

            Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));


            // Request Signature using Template

            url = baseURL + "/envelopes";             

            string requestBody =
                "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                    "<status>sent</status>" +
                    "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template</emailSubject>" +
                    "<documents>" +
                       "<document>" +
                          "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                          "<name>Testdoc.pdf</name>" +
                          //"<PDFBytes>" + Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes) + "</PDFBytes>" +
                      "</document>" +
                   "</documents>" +
                    "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
                    "<templateRoles>" +
                        "<templateRole>" +
                            "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                            "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
                            "<roleName>" + templateRole + "</roleName>" +
                        "</templateRole>" +
                    "</templateRoles>" +
                "</envelopeDefinition>";



            request = initializeRequest(url, "POST", requestBody, username, password, integratorKey);
           // request.ContentType = "application/pdf";



            response = getResponseBody(request);

            Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));
```

Comment: You're actually attempting a relatively complicated workflow very early on with your development, if I were you I'd first get a single template workflow working before attempting this.  To provide some more info though, you are going to need to use **Composite Templates** to combine a template with a document.  Please see the API Reference Guide for more info on Composite Templates.

Comment: @Ergin, I'm able to upload document through API call. But I'm unable to apply server template to the uploaded document. I tried using composite templates as you suggested but it uploads template document (stored in my web account) in the envelope instead of the actual document that I'm sending through API. Any ideas on how to apply server template to the document? I'm using C# and XML for the API call. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do that (taken from Gil's blog post - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates/):

```
"compositeTemplates": [{
    "serverTemplates": [{
    "sequence": "1",
    "templateId": "741c8b4c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c03acb1a3993"
    }],
    "inlineTemplates": [{
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
        "email": "joe.bloggs@example.com",
        "name": "Joe Bloggs",
        "roleName": "customer"
        }]
    },
    "sequence": "2"
    }]
}]
```

Hope this helps!